# How to install Waeup on window and get it running

Tags: python, pycharm, grok

I'm trying to install waeup on my window computer but for some reason it fails to install some dependency

Comment: What is that "some reason" exactly, please edit and add the error message being generated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.